# Unwanted directory mounting on boot

Tags: centos6, boot, mount

Currently there is a directory that is mounting over another directory on boot. I cannot figure out for the life of me where this is coming from. The problem mount is the last mount on the **df -ah** output...

**UPDATE:** 
A little more color. The **/gfs2** directory below is a legacy directory on the root partition. I want to mount the **/dev/mapper/vg_prodapi01-LogVol01** directly to the **/sitelogs** directory without it getting mounted over by this legacy **/gfs2** directory on boot.

**df -ah** output

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_prodapi01-LogVol01
                       18G   12G  5.9G  66% /
proc                     0     0     0   -  /proc
sysfs                    0     0     0   -  /sys
devpts                   0     0     0   -  /dev/pts
tmpfs                 3.9G   32M  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             291M   65M  212M  24% /boot
none                     0     0     0   -  /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
none                     0     0     0   -  /sys/kernel/config
sunrpc                   0     0     0   -  /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs
/dev/mapper/vg_prodcluster-lv_gfs2
                       18G   12G  5.9G  66% /sitelogs
/gfs2/sitelogs         18G   12G  5.9G  66% /sitelogs #problem mount
```

Here are my configs:

**/etc/fstab**

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Jun 28 08:12:10 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/vg_prodapi01-LogVol01 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=37913101-3d09-4eec-9c99-608827d5e9a7 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_prodapi01-LogVol00 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_prodcluster-lv_gfs2  /sitelogs   gfs2    defaults    0 0
```

**rc.local**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

touch /var/lock/subsys/local
```

Here is also my boot log file

**/var/log/boot.log**

```
G       Welcome to CentOS
Starting udev: G                                           [  OK  ]
Setting hostname prodapi01.domain.com:                [  OK  ]
Setting up Logical Volume Management:   Skipping clustered volume group vg_prodcluster
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_prodapi01" now active
                                                           [FAILED]
Checking filesystems
_CentOS-6.4-x86_: clean, 393237/1163264 files, 3049229/4638720 blocks
/dev/sda1: clean, 48/76912 files, 75666/307200 blocks
                                                           [  OK  ]
Remounting root filesystem in read-write mode:             [  OK  ]
Mounting local filesystems:                                [  OK  ]
Enabling local filesystem quotas:                          [  OK  ]
Enabling /etc/fstab swaps:                                 [  OK  ]
Entering non-interactive startup
Calling the system activity data collector (sadc):
Starting monitoring for VG vg_prodapi01:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_prodapi01" monitored
                                                           [  OK  ]
   Checking acpi hot plug                                  [  OK  ]
Starting VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
   Switching to guest configuration:                       [  OK  ]
   VM communication interface:                             [  OK  ]
   VM communication interface socket family:               [  OK  ]
   Guest operating system daemon:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:                                [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth2:                                [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth4:                                [  OK  ]
Starting auditd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting portreserve:                                      [  OK  ]
Starting system logger:                                    [  OK  ]
Starting irqbalance:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting kdump:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting lldpad:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting cluster:
   Checking if cluster has been disabled at boot...        [  OK  ]
   Checking Network Manager...                             [  OK  ]
   Global setup...                                         [  OK  ]
   Loading kernel modules...                               [  OK  ]
   Mounting configfs...                                    [  OK  ]
   Starting cman...                                        [  OK  ]
   Waiting for quorum...                                   [  OK  ]
   Starting fenced...                                      [  OK  ]
   Starting dlm_controld...                                [  OK  ]
   Tuning DLM kernel config...                             [  OK  ]
   Starting gfs_controld...                                [  OK  ]
   Unfencing self...                                       [  OK  ]
   Joining fence domain...                                 [  OK  ]
Starting FCoE initiator service:                           [  OK  ]

Starting system message bus:                               [  OK  ]
Starting clvmd:
Activating VG(s):   1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_prodcluster" now active
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg_prodapi01" now active
                                                           [  OK  ]
Starting NFS statd:                                        [  OK  ]
Initializing OpenCT smart card terminals:                  [  OK  ]

Starting RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting cups:                                             [  OK  ]
Mounting other filesystems:                                [  OK  ]
Starting acpi daemon:                                      [  OK  ]
Mounting GFS2 filesystem (/sitelogs):                      [  OK  ]
Starting HAL daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Retrigger failed udev events                               [  OK  ]
Starting PC/SC smart card daemon (pcscd):                  [  OK  ]
Loading autofs4:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting automount:                                        [  OK  ]
Enabling Bluetooth devices:
Starting snmpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting ntpd:                                             [  OK  ]
Starting postfix:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting puppet-agent: Loading launcher_prod_tier_2_rc...
Starting crond:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting atd:                                              [  OK  ]
Cleaning up /opt/simpana/Base/Temp ...
Starting Simpana services for Instance001 ...
Starting saslauthd:                                        [  OK  ]
Starting Cluster Module - cluster monitor:                 [  OK  ]
Starting Cluster Service Manager:                          [  OK  ]
Starting oddjobd:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting ricci:                                            [  OK  ]
```

Comment: This looks "right" to me, do you not intend for /sitelogs to be written to a shared GFS2 file system?

Comment: Let me add a little more color. The /gfs2 directory is a legacy directory that the previous sysadmin had set up as a loopback mount.What I want to do is just mount the disk directly to the /sitelogs directory as indicated in the fstab.

Answer (score 1):

We have pinpointed the issue. This is ridiculous. The previous sysadmin had created an init script to make the directory and mount it on boot without outputting anything.

**Lesson for everyone --  please use standard configurations and save the sanity of the next person ahead of you.**